# selenium grid2 use custom browser path in json config

Tags: json, selenium, grid

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 21, Selenium Grid2 with selenium protocol is 'Selenium, and use DefaultSelenium in java code. I want to use json config file to start node, the json is :

```
{  "capabilities": [  { "browserName": "*firefox",
"seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","firefox_binary":"/home/fs/software/firefox/firefox",
"platform": "LINUX", "maxInstances": 3 }],  "configuration": {
"nodeTimeout":120, "port":5555, "hubPort":4444, "hubHost":"localhost",
"nodePolling":2000, "registerCycle":10000, "register":true,
"cleanUpCycle":2000, "timeout":30000, "maxSession":1, }  }
```

but when run the junit test, it always says : Firefox3 cannot be found in the path.
I have another firefox 31, it is installed by default, and if I delete 'firefox_binary' in json, then I can run the junit test with opening Firefox 31.

So if I want to use custom browser path, how should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I used new FirefoxDriver() in code, after changed it to

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

it works! It will start custom firefox.